# Exception using DB2 Wirelistener (NoSQL) from a Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, nosql, db2

I have set up DB2 as NoSQL storage (following https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1306nosqlforjson4/index.html). The premise by IBM is that any application talking to MongoDB can switch to DB2 if we add the Wire Listener in between.

The layout is: Client app ----> Wire listener ----> DB2

Wire listener is started with the following command:

```
wlpListener -start -mongoPort 27017 -userid <user> -password <password> -dbName jsondb -logPath c:/temp/logs -host 10.0.0.6:50000
```

The solution works fine with a simple Python client:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('10.0.0.6', 27017)
database = client['jsondb']
coll = database.mycollection
coll.insert_one({"name":"Jerry","age":5})
print(coll.find_one({"name": "Jerry"}))
```

However, when I use a Spring Boot application designed for MongoDB (using Spring Data JPA) I get the following exception during initialization:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.2)

2021-02-14 11:13:28.629  INFO 11820 --- [           main] c.i.a.n.generator.gen.MainGenerator      : Starting MainGenerator using Java 1.8.0 on SP-NIT09160021 with PID 11820 (C:\Users\user\Documents\Workspaces\nosql-poc-db2-wirednosql\target\classes started by user in C:\Users\user\Documents\Workspaces\nosql-poc-db2-wirednosql)
2021-02-14 11:13:28.635  INFO 11820 --- [           main] c.i.a.n.generator.gen.MainGenerator      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-02-14 11:13:29.375  INFO 11820 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-02-14 11:13:29.450  INFO 11820 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 69 ms. Found 3 MongoDB repository interfaces.
2021-02-14 11:13:30.006  INFO 11820 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-02-14 11:13:30.016  INFO 11820 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-02-14 11:13:30.016  INFO 11820 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.41]
2021-02-14 11:13:30.132  INFO 11820 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-02-14 11:13:30.132  INFO 11820 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1414 ms
2021-02-14 11:13:30.304  INFO 11820 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[10.0.0.6:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}
2021-02-14 11:13:30.380  INFO 11820 --- [-10.0.0.6:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 10.0.0.6:27017
com.mongodb.MongoException: org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: Value expected to be of type INT32 is of unexpected type DOUBLE
             at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:157) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
             at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
             at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:144) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785) [na:1.8.0-internal]
Caused by: org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: Value expected to be of type INT32 is of unexpected type DOUBLE
             at org.bson.BsonValue.throwIfInvalidType(BsonValue.java:419) ~[bson-4.1.1.jar:na]
             at org.bson.BsonValue.asInt32(BsonValue.java:94) ~[bson-4.1.1.jar:na]
             at org.bson.BsonDocument.getInt32(BsonDocument.java:555) ~[bson-4.1.1.jar:na]
             at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DescriptionHelper.getMaxWireVersion(DescriptionHelper.java:104) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
             at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DescriptionHelper.createConnectionDescription(DescriptionHelper.java:63) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
             at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:117) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
             at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:62) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
             at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:144) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
             ... 3 common frames omitted
```

As if there was an incompatibility between the Mongo driver and what the Wire Listener expects.

Versions:

- Host system: Windows 10
- Database server: DB2/LINUXX8664 11.5.5.0 (using the Docker container from https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/db2 )
- IBM DB2 NoSQL WireListener 1.4.0.0 build 1.4.118
- IBM DB2 NoSQL JSON 1.1.0.0 build 1.4.249
- Java application (1.8 jdk), Spring Boot 2.4.2, [Mongodb.bson, mongodb-driver-core, mongodb-driver-sync] 4.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the Wire Listener.

The MongoDB driver expects an Int:

```
    private static int getMinWireVersion(final BsonDocument isMasterResult) {
        return isMasterResult.getInt32("minWireVersion", new BsonInt32(getDefaultMinWireVersion())).getValue();
    }

    private static int getMaxWireVersion(final BsonDocument isMasterResult) {
        return isMasterResult.getInt32("maxWireVersion", new BsonInt32(getDefaultMaxWireVersion())).getValue();
    }
```

But the Wire Listener is reporting a Double.

[image: Values from the Wire Listener]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to get latest IBM DB2 NoSQL WireListener from IBM Support that contains fix of this issue.
If you have no issue in downloading quick fix from github, you can download and use this file: https://github.com/ibmdb/db2drivers/blob/main/db2NoSQLWireListener1.4.119.zip
it contains fix of this issue. Thanks.